# How to open dynamically created files in django

Tags: python, django, python-tesseract

okay my head hurts, i created 2 models one for image and one for file, each time i upload an image a file is automatically created containing the OCR result of the image.
However my files are not being stored  into the file folder and i can't seem to open them.

here is my code please help me guys i've been stuck not understanding how to pass the text to the fileField so that it can deal with it as a normal fileField upload:

```js
class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='media',unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.id :
            File.objects.create(
                file=Create_Pdf(self.image))
            File.objects.update(title=self.title)
         
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

this is my File model :

```js
    from django.db.models.fields import related
    from django.db import models
    # Create your models here.


    class File(models.Model):
        label=models.CharField(max_length=50, default='none')
        title=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='test')
        file=models.FileField(upload_to='files')
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
```

```js
and this is the use case :
import uuid
import os
import pytesseract
import PIL.Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
def Create_Pdf(image):
   filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.pdf"
   path=r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\PFE Rihab\Django j\OCRapplication\media\files'#i know this is wrong i just wanted to save the files and view them.
   image=PIL.Image.open(image)
   text=pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
   with open (os.path.join(path,filename),mode='w+')as f:
       f.write(text)
   return(text)#i m not sure i should be returning text since it just gives me the OCR result as a link
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you need to wrap the outpout of the OCR with a `ContentFile`

docs here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class

> The ContentFile class inherits from File, but unlike File it operates
> on string content (bytes also supported), rather than an actual file.

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='media',unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.id :
            File.objects.create(
                file=ContentFile(Create_Pdf(self.image)),  # <--- Here
                title=self.title
            )
         
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

If you want my 2cent, a `TextField` field named `result` in `Image` model, is more simple and straigtforward.

Comment: I actually tried that, but sadly it is not working, it's not creating any file

Comment: i actually figured it out, it was very simple actually i had to provide a name for the file i m creating for the contentFile to be stored lol , thank you very much for helping